# Querying states of widgets defined by a QT ui file

Tags: qt

I have a ui file, created in QT designer, which I've used to create a dialog at runtime using the `QUiLoader` class. Is it possible to query the states of all widgets in this dialog when the dialog closes? I can traverse the widget hierarchy from the root widget but I don't know how to trigger this traversal when the dialog closes.

Comment: Sort of like how Java Swing's API? Since QWidget is a QObject, you should be able to access [QObject::children](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#properties) member function.

Comment: I can access child objects. The real question is _how_ to trigger the traversal. I've considered signals, actions but am drawing blanks.

Comment: Oh I see now, yeah the SIGNAL(closing()) or what have you sounds like the way to go.  That is unless you've extended the QDialog class!

Comment: No I have not extended the dialog class. Besides, in spite of how I phrased my question, not all ui files have a top level dialog object. As such there is no guarantee of the closing() signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be to install an event filter for the loaded `QWidget` from the `QUiLoader`. In the `eventFilter` method, you could catch the hide event (triggered by dialogs either by accept or reject slot). 
For exaple the header file would look like this:

**MyApplicationObject.h**

```
#include <QObject>

class MyApplicationObject : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit MyApplicationObject(QObject *parent = 0);
   ~MyApplicationObject() {}

   bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);

private:
   QWidget *m_dialog;
};
```

And here the implementation file:

**MyApplicationObject.h**

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QtUiTools/QUiLoader>
#include "MyApplicationObject.h"

MyApplicationObject::MyApplicationObject(QObject *parent) :
   QObject(parent)
{
   QUiLoader loader;
   QFile file(":/dialogs/dialog1");
   file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

   m_dialog = loader.load(&file);
   m_dialog->installEventFilter(this);

   file.close();

   m_dialog->show();
}

bool MyApplicationObject::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
   if (object == m_dialog) {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::Hide) {
         qDebug("Do something with dialog widget if dialog was accepted or rejected");
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   } else {
      // Call base implementation
      return QMainWindow::eventFilter(object, event);
   }
}
```